# EQ opinions for room shaping

Tags: equalization

I am looking for a hardware EQ just to shape the room any opinions on brand,

model?

Thanx

Comment: You mean room correction (as in room acoustics)?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific, i ment plain jane eq or para analog, I would rather do the work.

Thanx Again

Answer (score 2):

use a lot of:

http://www.atsacoustics.com/item--Owens-Corning-703-Case-of-6--1004.html

You cannot correct room resonances or modes with EQ, it is really the wrong approach, you can use an EQ just to fine tune the room balance. 
If your problem is your room sounding bad, do not buy any kind of room correction tool it will not solve the problem.

Comment: thanx for that will look into it alot cheaper than an EQ

Bill

Answer (score 0):

If it's room correction you're looking for, I'm using a KRK Ergo at home, works very well in my opinion. Considering the price of sound proofing/acoustic treatment it's a decent option (especially if you can get one 2nd hand) Have a look - http://www.krksys.com/krk-ergo.html

Comment: Also, the budget solution http://www.behringer.com/EN/Products/DEQ2496.aspx . It can read files generated by RoomEQ Wizard (the free room measurement and filter design software).

Comment: Looks quite good, shame it's so big.

Comment: @Adrian In all fairness however, the KRK device is quite distant from the norm in that it's a small desk unit. 95% of outboard hardware gear (such as Behringer, DBX, Bluesky, Eventide, Cedar, Dolby, and so on) are designed as rackmount units on purpose.  The fact that this Behringer device is only 1U is in fact quite small.  EQ boxes, especially for room tuning, can usually be 2U per stereo, so for a 5.1 setup your taking abut 6U total - 3 of these Behringers in-line for a 5.1 system would only take up 3U.